# Keep track of successful pin in Bandit CTF 24 to 25

Tags: shell-script, scripting, netcat, nc

I am doing the bandit wargame of OverTheWire and am trying to pass [level 24 -> 25](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit25.html). I successfully got the password with the script below but I'd like to recover the successful pin. I tried implementing a counter but was unsuccessful. Do you have any idea on how I could proceed ?

Code:

```
for i in {0000..9999};
do 
  echo UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i; 
done | nc localhost 30002
```

Comment: I wanted to do the same. It seems that there is no way to let `nc` close the connection immediately after receiving a string. You should do `echo UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i | nc localhost 30002;`, but the lowest timeout that can be set as an option for `nc` is 1 second, which is too much for a 4-digit brute-force attempt. I tried something like `timeout 0.6 echo UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i | nc localhost 30002;` (0.6 is the number of seconds). But the output is confusing and in *some* pin attempts the timeout seems too short and `nc` may not have produced an output.

Comment: The answers do not provide a way to recover the actual pin. In the update of the original post, the code outputs an error : `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token "echo"`

Comment: @GAD3R Please, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523269/48707) lets you to correctly guess the pin. It is currently the **only** answer in the [mentioned page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432904/brute-force-4-digit-pin-with-pass-using-shell-script) which is useful for your problem.

Using that script, every output line from `nc` generates a new line in file `f.txt`. The first line of `f.txt` is

```
I am the pincode checker for user...
```

and it doesn't count. The second line corresponds to pin `0000`. So, the `n`th line corresponds to pin `n - 2`. If you run the script, line `2590` contains the word `Correct!`, which means that the pin is `2590 - 2 = 2588`. This is confirmed by the file

```
-rw-r-----  1 bandit25 bandit25    4 May 14 14:04 .pin
```

in the `bandit25` home directory.

---

I do not think this question is duplicate, because here the pin is explicitly requested, while in the [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432904/brute-force-4-digit-pin-with-pass-using-shell-script) it is not. Moreover, the linked question has not yet a chosen answer, which may create confusion between the readers: it's not trivial to guess which of the 6 answers is the actually suitable one.